# Is it possible to retrive a text file from an NXT?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, 3rd-party

I am on a [SeaPerch](http://seaperch.mit.edu/index.php) building team which is starting to use a [Vernier Dissolved Oxygen probe](http://www.vernier.com/products/sensors/do-bta/), connected to an NXT to log the data. I have a bit of programming experience, but nothing in particular with NXTs (or GUI programming for that matter) and managed to get a very simple program written which logs data collected from the probe to a text file stored on the NXT (there will be no computer available in the field, so everything has to be stored on the NXT).

My problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to get the file from the NXT's memory and copied to a computer. It doesn't seem to be able to be accessed from Windows Explorer as a drive. Is it possible to get files off of it like a flash drive, or would I need to do something else to get the data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Mindstorms NXT software (NXT-G), you can transfer any file from NXT to computer. Open "NXT window" (NXT icon in the lower right corner of interface), then go to "memory" tab. Select a file in NXT and click on "upload" button.

Or - more convenient - you may use "NXT Explorer" feature of [BricxCC](http://bricxcc.sourceforge.net/) (in the "tools" menu).

Comment: we did this, but it won't open...

Comment: We do not see an icon in the lower right corner.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just an answer to the @laurentien comment posted in the existing answer.

---

The "NXT window" icon is the orange L-shaped button (see red arrow).

The "memory" tab is the other red arrow.

[image]